# To show master view alone in portrait mode

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using a `UISplitViewcontroller` in my iPad app. My requirement is to show just the master view in portrait mode and both master and detail in landscape mode. I tried using a SplitView controller, but it only shows the detail view in portrait mode.

The delegate function `splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:` will show both master and detail in portrait, but that is not my requirement.

Also it is only supported from iOS 5.0 and my app should support iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

put 
 
`self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.allVisible`
 
 
in your `MasterViewController`